# Division that preserve the sum

Tags: algorithm, division

I need a function *f* which takes two integer parameter -- a dividend *A* and a divisor *B* -- and returns an array of integer quotients *C1, C2, ..., Cn* such as *C1 + C2 + ... + Cn = A* and the reminder of *A* and *B* is "equally distributed".

For example:

- f (9, 3) = [3, 3, 3]
- f (10, 3) = [4, 3, 3]
- f (11, 3) = [4, 4, 3] (and not just [5, 3, 3])

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, is there such a function somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the function to be `f(x,y)`, and ***every variable to be positive valued integers***, the sample algorithm is:

1. Divide x by y, and store remainder as r, quotient as q.
2. `for( i=1; i<=r; i++ )`

   `element[i] = q + 1;`
    `// assuming the array index starts from 1.`

That's it. You've your elements stored in `element[]` array.

Answer (score 0):

This is a greedy algorithm. The remainder is at most `Y - 1` for any divisor `Y`. So distribute the remainder 1 to each quotient in greedy manner. There is no way that there will be remainder left after distributing 1 to each or one quotient will receive more than 1.

```
f(X, Y):
    q = X / Y
    r = X % Y
    while r not equal to 0
        print q + 1
        r := r - 1
        Y := Y - 1
    end

    while Y not equal 0
        print q
        Y := Y - 1
    end
end
```

This will work if `X` and `Y` are both non-negative and `Y > 0`. If `Y` is greater than `X`, it will still handle this.

Answer (score -1):

Highly doubt there is one. One can however be implemented quite easily. You can get the number of elements in said array with `B` and number with 1 above `A % B`